# Пространство имен в php

Tags: php, phalcon

Класс

```
<?php namespace Korol;
class Service {

    public function test() {
        return 'test';
    }


}
?>
```

Использование

```
use Korol as ariya;
$test = new ariya\Service();
echo  $test->test();
```

Без пространства работает подключается так

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

$loader->registerDirs(array(
    __DIR__ . '/models/',
    __DIR__ . '/modules/mail/'
))->register();
```

Ошибка

> Fatal error: Class 'Korol\Service' not found in
>   D:\Servera\Last\OpenServer\domains\portfolio\resource\index.php on
>   line 110

Netbeans  видит вроде как
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В общем методом тыка получилось вот так

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

$loader->registerDirs(array(
    __DIR__ . '/models/'
))->registerNamespaces(
        array(
            "Korol\Ariya" => "modules/mail/"
        )
)->register();

$test = new Korol\Ariya\MailerService();
echo $test->test();
```

Но приходится писать такое обращение Korol\Ariya\MailerService();